# Is it possible to sign a Passbook manifest using node.js and crypto?

Tags: node.js, certificate, digital-signature, private-key, passbook

I'm trying to figure out how to sign an iOS Passbook pass manifest.json using node.js and crypto. It seems like it should be possible but I can't seem to create a proper signature.

Here's is what I've tried:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var fs = require('fs');

var manifest = fs.readFileSync('manifest.json');
var pem = fs.readFileSync('passbookdemo.pem');
var key = pem.toString('ascii');

var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(manifest);
var sig = sign.sign(key);

fs.writeFileSync('signature');
```

I generated the passbookdemo.pem earlier using:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in passbookdemo.p12 -out passbookdemo.pem -nodes
```

There is no passphrase associated with passbookdemo.pem.

One possible problem I can see is that I'm not incorporating the Apple developer relations certificate during the signing process, which I believe is a requirement.

Another possibility is that I'm using the incorrect argument in `crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');`. I'm not sure what I should use instead.

Here's a sample of ruby code that Apple supplied that I was able to use to sign the manifest correctly.

```
def sign_manifest
    puts "Signing the manifest"
    # Import the certificates
    p12_certificate = OpenSSL::PKCS12::new(File.read(self.certificate_url), self.certificate_password)
    wwdr_certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(self.wwdr_intermediate_certificate_path))

    # Sign the data
    flag = OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY|OpenSSL::PKCS7::DETACHED
    signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(p12_certificate.certificate, p12_certificate.key, File.read(self.manifest_url), [wwdr_certificate], flag)

    # Create an output path for the signed data
    self.signature_url = self.temporary_path + "/signature"

    # Write out the data
    File.open(self.signature_url, "w") do |f|
        f.syswrite signed.to_der
    end
end
```

Some related resources:

- [How to use NodeJS crypto to sign a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683189/how-to-use-nodejs-crypto-to-sign-a-file)
- Signing a pass using openssl - https://github.com/assaf/node-passbook/blob/master/lib/pass.js#L342
- Crypto docs - http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign
- [Cannot generate Apple Passbook signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650075/cannot-generate-apple-passbook-signature?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been five years since this was written but I came across it and thought it deserved an answer. 
Yes it is possible.
[Here is an example script](https://github.com/destinationstransfers/passkit/blob/master/bin/passkit-keys) that calls `openssl` from node.